# Fitting polynomials with additional functions

Tags: python, regression

Suppose I have an array called `Y` and another array called `X`. I know how to fit a polynomial using `numpy.polyfit()` and as output I will get an array with coefficients. But what if I want to add some function `f(x)` as an additional regressor to the polynomial, how can I do that in python?

For example `Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `X = [101,102,103,104,105,106]`. I know how to estimate coefficients of `y = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3` (the polynomial of order 3), I can estimate it using `z = numpy.polyfit(Y, X, 3)`. Now, I want to estimate `y = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 + a_4f(x)` where `f(x)` is some function. I am new to Python, couldn't find answer on Google

Comment: There is no general answer, but look into `scipy.optimize`. A quite general but relative slow solution is to use `scipy.optimize.brent`. A faster, but more difficult cumbersome way is to use `scipy.optimize.lbfgsb`

Comment: @NathanThomas Hello! I dont understand what you mean by "showing us what you have done". It is not homework task to show my progress, what do you expect me to do? To write my own python code instead of numpy.polyfit? I am asking if there are some already implemented functions that can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.optimize.curve_fit` is what you are looking for. It can take any arbitrary function, and thus you can define both the polynomial term and the extra functional term in that function.

```
def f(x, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4):
  func_term = np.exp(-abs(x))  # can be anything you need
  return a0 + a1 * x + a2 * x**2 + a3 * x**3 + a4 * func_term
```

and then fit the curve:

```
popt, _ = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata)
```

Comment: I have expanded your answer with code for a graphical fitter using the function you supplied here. Your answer is directly to the point, mine is somewhat more long-winded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for a graphical fitter using the example function provided in Gerges Dib's answer. Note that scipy's curve_fit() is a non-linear solver that requires initial parameter estimates as a starting point, and these all have the value of 1.0 by default if you do not supply any yourself. Here you can see that the result of the fit visually looks OK, but if that were not the case it might have been due to the initial parameter estimates - this sometimes happens. Scipy has a genetic algorithm to help determine the initial parameter estimates, in this example that was not required.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(x, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4): # Gerges Dib gave this example function
    func_term = numpy.exp(-abs(x))  # can be anything you need
    return a0 + a1 * x + a2 * x**2 + a3 * x**3 + a4 * func_term


fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    axes.set_title('Gerges Dib example function')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful!

Comment: To very poorly paraphrase Isaac Newton, as regards my code: "If I seem tall, it is because I stand on the shoulders of Gerges".